# Add/remove CSS styles after 976px width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

```
/*Fade in effect & one pager*/
.fullpage-wrapper {
    width: 100%!important;
    transform: none!important;
}

.fp-section {
    width: 100%!important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.fp-section.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Remove transition when website is still loading */
body {display:none}
body[class*="fp-viewing-"] {display:block}
```

I want to remove these given styles below 976px width for mobile users. How can I accomplish this in javascript or jquery? Also it's possible to leave the else open right?

```
if ($(window).width() < 967) {
   *remove these styles but how?*
}
else {
   *keep them/or do nothing*
}
```

Comment: Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: OP said:`How can I accomplish this in javascript or jquery?` not css

Comment: Use the `matchMedia` api.

Comment: You don't need any JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use just css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 967px) {
    /*Your styles */
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a solution in JS or jQuery.

Comment: You are correct this did the job.. I've been stuck on this site/issues 2 days and it's driving me nuts. I totally overlooked this solution

Answer (score 2):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 967px) {
    .fullpage-wrapper {
        width: 100%!important;
        transform: none!important;
    }

.    fp-section {
        width: 100%!important;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
    }

    .fp-section.active {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Remove transition when website is still loading */
    body {display:none}
    body[class*="fp-viewing-"] {display:block}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/my5Luevc/

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() < 967) {
    $('div').addClass('width976');
  }
  else {
     $('div').removeClass('width976');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.width976{
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

On resize of the screen you can see the class is being dynamically added & removed.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and the [fadingEffect extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html), as your code and tags seems to point out, then you can make use of fullPage.js callbacks and functions to solve this in the proper way:

```
$('#fullpage').fullPage({
    responsiveWidth: 976,
    afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){
        if(isResponsive){
            $.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOff();
        }
        else{
            $.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOn();
        }
    }
});
```